# My shopping cart is adding duplicate amounts

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem (must be with the javascript) on my shop.
I go to this page and select Add to Cart on one of the items: http://www.proxyplayer.co.uk/NewSite/?page_id=4
It gets added as 1 item into the shopping cart on the right sidebar. I then click View Cart but as soon as the checkout page appears it is suddenly 2 items

I tried looking through firebug and found that there is a blank background-image: url()
which causes a double submission.
ANy ideas how I can fix this?

```
/* Background */
    #show-space,
    #inner-page-show-space {
        background-color: #ff9f12;
        background-image: url();
    }
```

Comment: The background image is not the issue. Post your relevant code, both HTML and javascript, for 'Add to Cart'. Also, post your form code.

Comment: This is a known bug though: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=473528 & http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/integration/known-conflicts/ no?

Comment: The code was working until I updated a theme and suddenyl it stopped, which I think might imply that the theme or css is the problem as I did not change any javascript in the update

Comment: Why don't you just remove the `background-image: url();` line?

Comment: I'm not sure how to find it as I'm using a theme and some plugins. I used view source to find that it was blank but am not sure how to use fire bug to find it. I tried seraching in firebug for the words backgrouns-image but it doesn't find them

Comment: How did you add the new theme? The CSS is embedded in the HTML file itself. Or PHP. Do you have access to the server?

Comment: Fix the typo in your search, Firebug will find it for you...

Comment: LOL, the typo was in this comment only :) I found it and added a background image and it stops the bug in FF only. So, I suppose I need to add a transparent background image to workaround it...

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your javascript `onload`:

```
document.getElementById("inner-page-show-space").style.backgroundImage = "url('a dummy image url')";
```

This will override the definition in CSS.